# Performing `distinct` on more than one field in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to retrieve all the tuples over two certain fields in my MongoDB collection. For example, saying I have documents representing people, with fields such as `first_name`, `last_name` and `age`, and I wish to get all the full names in my collection. If I only needed to find all the first names, I would have done the following:

```
People.distinct(:first_name)
```

But since I need a list of all the full names, what I'm looking for is a way to supply two fields to the `distinct` method. Unfortunately, the following is incorrect:

```
People.distinct(:first_name, :last_name)
```

How can I perform the `distinct` operation on more than a single field?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `distinct()` in Mongo - [distinct only takes a single field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

However, you should be able to use the aggregation framework to get what you need:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: {first_name: "$first_name", last_name: "$last_name"}}}
])
```

You'll have to iterate and extract the first/last name from each record rather than receiving an array back from Mongo, but it'll get you what you need.

Comment: I can't find a way to perform the equivalent query in mongoid. Is it even possible?

Comment: Try `YourModel.collection.aggregate`.

Comment: The downside is that you don't get model instances when you go through the AF, you just get Hashes. The usual approach (AFAIK) is to store a `full_name` in the database, manually keep it up to date as the first and last names change (and sanity check it periodically to make sure you don't have any update bugs), and then work with that generated value.